# What does $^@ (dollar caret at) mean in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

I found references for parameter expansion, but none of them explain what `$^@` does. From context, I think it's used to expand e.g. `~/$^@` into `~/$1 ~/$2 ...`, but I'm not sure, and I can't find any confirmation. In addition to an explanation, I'd appreciate knowing what this expansion is called, and a link to documentation about it if possible. Thanks!

EDIT: I've been informed this might be particular to zsh. If anyone has further information, please let me know.

Comment: Was this by any chance a `zsh` script?  That shell would be able to do exactly that, and it means exactly what you have described, it appends a string to all elements of an array. I'm not turning this into a proper answer as I don't know for sure what shell the script was written for (there may be other shells that does something similar, Stéphane would know).

Comment: You should provide the real code.

Comment: Yes, it's zsh. I didn't know that was relevant. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, the code can be as simple as `echo ~/$^@`

Comment: But if you are not using `zsh` then `echo ~/$^@` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Read `man zsh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell, `foo${^array}bar`, where `array` is an array, like `(a b c)`, would expand to `fooabar`, `foobbar`, and `foocbar` (like a brace expansion would expand) instead of to the strings `fooa`, `b`, and `cbar`:

```bsh
$ array=(a b c)
$ print -rC1 foo${^array}bar
fooabar
foobbar
foocbar
$ print -rC1 foo${array}bar
fooa
b
cbar
```

In the code that you quote, this is used to append `~/` (the pathname of the user's home directory) to each element of the list of positional parameters:

```bsh
$ set -- a b c "bumble bee"
$ print -rC1 ~/$^@
/home/myself/a
/home/myself/b
/home/myself/c
/home/myself/bumble bee
```

`~/$^@` is the same as `~/${^@}`.  `$@` or `${@}` is the list of positional parameters (commonly the arguments given to the current script or shell function, or the strings set with the `set` built-in utility, as shown above).

Search the `zshall` manual for `RC_EXPAND_PARAM`.  The expansion may originally come from [the `rc` shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc).

Comment: That's what `rc` does by default, and see the `^` operator there as well. But the behaviour is different when joining two arrays. Compare `rc -c 'a=(a b); echo $a^X'` with `zsh -c 'a=(a b); echo ${^a}X'` and `rc -c 'a=(a b); echo $a^$a'` vs `zsh -c 'a=(a b); echo $^a$^a'`. The behaviour of `zsh -o rcexpandparam` is more like the default behaviour of `fish` (`fish -c 'set a a b; echo $a$a'`)